# Удаление из пирамиды

Tags: алгоритм

Пытаюсь реализовать удаление **произвольного** элемента из пирамиды. Т.е нам дается индекс элемента в массиве, в котором содержится пирамида, и мы его должны удалить. По идее алгоритм такой: ставим на место удаляемого элемента последний элемент и запускаем либо просеивание вниз (sift_down) либо просеивание вверх (sift_up). Сначала я думал, что нужно выполнять только просеивание вниз, потом решил запускать и sift_down(i) и sift_up(i), где i - элемент который удаляем и на место которого поставили последний элемент. 
Вот так я примерно делаю.

```
heap[i] = heap[--heap_size]; // Ставим последний элемент на место удаляемого
sift_down(i); // Просеивание вниз
sift_up(i); // Просеивание вверх
```

Но такой алгоритм у меня не проходит на многих тестах(я не знаю на каких, знаю только что вердикт - Неправильный ответ). Подскажите как правильно восстановить пирамиду после того, как на место удаляемого элемента ставим последний.

З.Ы Решаю задачу [отсюда](http://informatics.mccme.ru/file.php/18/bin_heap_ig-091022.pdf)(страница 12, задача 5).

Comment: Пришлите пожалуйста sift_down(i); и sift_up(i);.

Comment: Вот полный код задачи. Там получается запросы трех типов, третий тип - это как раз удаление произвольного элемента. До этого решал задачу для обработки только запросов 1, 2 и проходило. Я уже все перепробовал но никак не могу сдать задачу полностью.
http://ideone.com/3tGmeA

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что проблема здесь в том, что при просеивании вниз, мы не можем использовать в чистом виде shift_down(...), так как есть неоднозначность: какой элемент следует менять. Я приведу пример:

[image: Пример]

Очевидно, что в этом случае есть некоторая неоднозначность. Предположим, что последний элемент равен 7. Тогда мы можем обменять 7 и 8, либо обменять местами 6 и 7. В первом случае, очевидно, структура кучи не нарушится. Во втором же, окажется, что один из пунктов определения окажется неверным, так как "всякий потомок должен быть меньше родителя", коль скоро у нас в корне лежит максимум (либо, если в корне лежит минимум, всякий потомок должен быть больше родителя). В данном случае приведён пример, когда в корне лежит максимум.

В таком случае, при просеивании вниз Вам нужно проверять как элемент `2 * i + 1`, так и `2 * i`, выбирая среди них нужный.

Понятно, что при просеивании вверх такого не происходит, так как предок у узла только один. Выбор оказывается однозначным.

Comment: Я как раз и проверяю оба элемента в sift_down, в 11-12 строках в коде на ideone можете глянуть. Только нумерация с нуля и потому я проверяю элементы 2 * i + 1 и 2 * i + 2.

Comment: Я не очень в код вчитывался. Я явно этого не увидел. Попробую потестировать его. Можно это сделать, на пример на heapSort'е. Т.е. удаляете элемент из пирамиды, восстанавливаете её. Затем сортим оставшиеся элементы. Это сделать нужно много раз на случайных данных.